# Blazor's RenderFragment, I want it to render to any location instead of a specific location. Is that possible?

Tags: blazor

Blazor's RenderFragment, I want it to render to any location instead of a specific location. Is that possible?

Let's say I get a RenderFragment and pass it to a Dom to render in

Comment: I tried to use js to pass the RenderFragment but couldn't do so. Is there another method to render the RenderFragment to the specified position?

I just want to render some components anywhere

Comment: See my answer, if it's not what you want can you provide some sort of example maybe in pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but you can define Razor markup in a `RenderFragment` property and then place it wherever you want in a form (multiple times if you wish).

Here's a simple example:

```cs
@page "/"

<div class="alert alert-danger">Some Data</div>
@HelloBlazor
<div class="alert alert-info">Some Data</div>
@HelloBlazor
<div class="alert alert-primary">Some Data</div>
@HelloBlazor
<div class="alert alert-dark">@HelloBlazor</div>


@code {
    private RenderFragment HelloBlazor => (__builder) =>
        {
            <div>Hello Blazor</div>
        };
}
```

Comment: I now embed blazor in applications that react does, but I want to embed blazor anywhere in react, not just inside blazor itself

Comment: Quite simply, I want to embed blazor in any existing project, it should be a component, and let me use it as I please